# Is there any way to detect or add an on-keypress/click event in search box of ng-multiselect-dropdown plugin

Tags: javascript, event-handling, angular6

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown for showing some checkbox and also filtering them based on search text. Now I wnt to detect or call a function every time user clicks in the search text but since it's a plugin, how can i detect or add the click event ?

Comment: Please share some code. Ideally on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown)

You can not detect or add the click event.

But you can achieve this using [ng-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the above ng-multiselect-dropdown link, there is an ability to detect on-keypress (which is what I wanted).

See `(onFilterChange)="onFilterChange($event)"`